# Is it possible to forward raw Security Onion data/logs to splunk (stand-alone) server for visualization?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard

I am trying to forward raw data collected by security onion to Splunk server installed in stand-alone mode

Answer (score 0):

There is an old add-on available at https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1095/.  It may not work, but should provide an example of how to connect Security Onion to Splunk.  See also the YouTube video at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwio-pzn0-fwAhWrKFkFHbxoDmEQwqsBMAt6BAgFEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dodg_B8MuGmE&usg=AOvVaw2SEnza0T56QLxNTv_7RaNd